# A proof without using net in Brezis's Ex 3.14

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, reflexive-space

I'm doing Ex 3.14 in Brezis's book of Functional Analysis.

> Let $E$ be a reflexive Banach space and $I$ a set of indices. Consider a collection $(f_{i})_{i \in I}$ in the dual space $E'$ and a collection $(\alpha_{i})_{i \in I}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $M>0$.
> Show that the following properties are equivalent:
>
> 1. There exists some $a \in E$ with $|a| \le M$ such that $\langle f_{i}, a\rangle=\alpha_{i}$ for every $i \in I$.
> 2. One has $|\sum_{i \in J} \beta_{i} \alpha_{i}| \leq M\|\sum_{i \in J} \beta_{i} f_{i}\|$ for every collection $(\beta_{i})_{i \in J}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with $J \subset I, J$ finite.

My below solution uses net characterization of compactness, which is probably not the author's intention.

Could you have a check on my attempt and suggest another solution without using net?

---

**My attempt:** WLOG, we can assume $M:=1$. The direction $1 \implies 2$ is trivial. Let's prove the converse. Let $B_E$ be the closed unit ball of $E$. Let $\mathcal J$ be the collection of all finite subsets of $I$. By [Helly's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371482/do-kakutanis-hellys-and-goldstines-theorems-all-hold-for-general-normed-lin) (*Lemma 3.3* in the book), for each $(J,n) \in \mathcal J \times \mathbb N$, there is $x_{J,n} \in B_E$ such that
$$
|\langle f_i, x_{J,n} \rangle - \alpha_i| < 1/n \quad \forall i \in J.
$$

We endow $\mathcal J \times \mathbb N$ with a partial order $\le$ defined by $(J, n) \le (J', n') \iff J \subseteq J' \text{ and } n \le n'$. Then $(\mathcal J \times \mathbb N, \le)$ is a directed set and thus $(x_{(J,n)})$ a net in $B_E$. Because $E$ is reflexive, $B_E$ is compact in weak topology $\sigma(E', E)$. Then there are $a \in B_E$ and a subnet $(x_{\varphi(d)})_{d\in D}$ such that $x_{\varphi(d)} \rightharpoonup a$. Next we prove that $a$ satisfies the requirement of 1.

Assume the contrary that there is $i_0 \in I$ such that $\langle f_{i_0}, a \rangle \neq \alpha_{i_0}$. There is $n_0$ such that $|\langle f_{i_0}, a \rangle - \alpha_{i_0}| > 1/n_0$. Let $J_0 := \{i_0\}$ and
$$
U := \{x\in E \mid |\langle f_{i_0}, x \rangle - \alpha_{i_0}| > 1/n_0\}.
$$

Then $U$ is an open neighborhood of $a$ in $\sigma(E', E)$. There is $d_0$ such that $x_{\varphi(d)} \in U$ for all $d \ge d_0$. There is $d_1 \ge d_0$ such that $\varphi(d_1) \ge (J_0, n_0+1)$. It follows that
$$
1/(n_0+1) > |\langle f_{i_0}, x_{\varphi(d_1)} \rangle - \alpha_{i_0}| > 1/n_0.
$$

This is a contradiction. This completes the proof.

Comment: (My comment is has nothing to do with the question) Hello. I'm studying functional analysis from Brezis, and I'm doing the exercises of chapter 3 too. If you agree, we could exchange ideas about them and about the theory.

Comment: $\phi: E\to \mathbb R^I$, $a\mapsto (f_i(a))_{i\in I}$ is linear and $(\sigma(E,E'),\tau)$-continuous where $\tau$ is the product topology. Since $E$ is reflexive, the unit ball $B$ is weakly compact and therefore $\phi(B)$ is also compact and hence closed. If $\alpha=(\alpha_i)_{i\in I}$ does not belong to $\phi(B)$ the separation theorem yields an element $\psi$ in the dual of $\mathbb R^I$ with $\sup\{\psi(\phi(a)): a\in B\} < \psi(\alpha)$. Using the continuity of $\psi$ with respect to the product topology, it is easy to see ...

Comment: ...that $\psi$ is of the form $\psi((x_i)_{i\in I})=\sum_{i\in J} \beta_ix_i$  for some finite $J$ and $\beta_i\in\mathbb R$. This yields the implication 2 $\Rightarrow$ 1 by contraposition.

Comment: @JohnMars Sure, we can exchange the ideas when we post questions on MSE.